# Particular Weyl group longest word

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, weyl-group

I was wondering if there is an algorithm for computing the Weyl group longest word starting with a particular choice.

For example, let $w_1$ and $w_2$ be defined as follows:

$$w_1= s_{i-1} s_{i-2} … s_1 s_{i-1} s_{i-2} … s_2 … s_{i-1} s_{i-2} s_{i-1};$$
$$w_2=s_{n} s_{n-1} … s_{j+1} s_{n} s_{n-1} … s_{j+2} … s_{n} s_{n-1} s_{n}.$$

How can we find the longest word $w_0$ of type $A$ starting with $w_1w_2$, assuming that $i<j$?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to start with these two? Because an obvious approach would be to take the inverse of these to get back to the identity and then apply a more usual process for finding the longest element such as found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54926/longest-element-of-weyl-groups)

Comment: @Callum I want to find a way to write the longest words starting with some subwords of less dimension, e.g. write the longest word of $A_6$ starting with $A_2$ indexed by 1,2 and then $A_2$ indexed by 5,6.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inductive procedure: for the group $S_2$ the longest word is $s_1$. For $S_3$ it is $s_1 s_2 s_1$. For $S_4$ it is

$$s_1 s_2 s_3 s_1 s_2 s_1,$$ and for $S_5$ it is
$$s_1 s_2 s_3 s_4 s_1 s_2 s_3 s_1 s_2 s_1.$$

The pattern should be clear. In general, if $w^{(n)}$ is the longest element of $S_n$, expressed as above as a reduced word, then
$$w^{(n+1)}=s_1 s_2 \cdots s_{n} w^{(n)}$$ is also a reduced word.

To prove this, observe that $w^{(n)}$ is the permutation given by
$$w^{(n)}(i)=n-i+1 \quad \hbox{for $1 \leq i \leq  n$.}$$ Its length is $n(n-1)/2$, the cardinality of the set of positive roots. Now use
$$(n+1)n/2=n+n(n-1)/2$$ and the fact that
$$s_1 s_2 \cdots s_{n-1}=(123\cdots n)$$ is the $n$-cycle.

As a side note, it is a nice fact about these particular reduced words for $w_0$ that a reduced word for any element of $S_n$ can be obtained by deleting letters in a certain way.

Comment: Great! Is there any analogues way for the other Dynkin types other than type A?

Comment: @F.H.A: I thought you were looking more generally for expressions starting with a particular choice. If not, general procedures for all types are given e.g. in answers to https://mathoverflow.net/q/54926.

Comment: @F.H.A As Torsten notes, there are expressions for all types. But I am not aware of an inductive procedure similar to this one outside type A (though I would be surprised if for classical types something similar cannot be made to work).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Well, to be fair the general procedures linked there aren't of the same inductive flavor (and do not share some of the favorable properties) as this type A version. For instance, as I hinted in the answer this also gives a preferred choice of reduced word for every element of the symmetric group. My opinion is that often, one should not think of the symmetric group as a certain Weyl group, but rather as its own creature, with its own peculiarities. Of course, many of its properties *do* generalize to arbitrary type in a nice way, but not all of them...